# nltk, cannot classify info into class

Tags: python, text, nltk

Need help with this, i have run codes below return with result as shown below.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')


import pandas as pd
news2=pd.read_table('/content/osha.txt',header=None,names = ["Class", "Text"])
news2.head()
b = news2.groupby("Class")
b.head()

news2.groupby('Class').describe()
```

[image]

Next, i attempt to inser the info into the list.

```
subnews2=news2[(news2.Class=="09employee Injures Hand")| (news2.Class=='29 Employees Burned')|(news2.Class=='3 Employees Killed') ]

subnews2.groupby('Class').describe()
print(subnews2.shape)
```

However the result returns zero rows of data have been inserted.

[image]

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: code `news2.Class=="09employee Injures Hand"` search rows with exactly `09employee Injures Hand` but you have `%09employee Injures Hand ... some other text...`. You may need to use `news2.Class.str.contains("09employee Injures Hand")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparision

```
news2.Class=="09employee Injures Hand"
```

searchs strings with exactly `09employee Injures Hand` but you have string with

```
%09employee Injures Hand ... some other text....
```

and this is the problem.

You may use `.str.contains()` for this.

```
news2.Class.str.contains("09employee Injures Hand")
```

And the same problem is with other strings.

```
subnews2 = news2[news2.Class.str.contains("09employee Injures Hand")|news2.Class.str.contains('29 Employees Burned')|news2.Class.str.contains('3 Employees Killed')]
```

Because it can uses `regex` so you can reduce it to single `.contains("...|...|...")`

```
subnews = news2[news2.Class.str.contains("09employee Injures Hand|29 Employees Burned|3 Employees Killed")]
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

news2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Class': ["09employee Injures Hand ...text...", '29 Employees Burned ...text...', '3 Employees Killed ...text...'],
  'Text': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
})    
#print(news2.head())

#b = news2.groupby("Class")
#print(b.head())
#print(news2.groupby('Class').describe())

subnews = news2[(news2.Class=="09employee Injures Hand")|(news2.Class=='29 Employees Burned')|(news2.Class=='3 Employees Killed')]
#print(subnews.groupby('Class').describe())
print(' ==       :', subnews.shape)

subnews2 = news2[news2.Class.str.contains("09employee Injures Hand")|news2.Class.str.contains('29 Employees Burned')|news2.Class.str.contains('3 Employees Killed')]
#print(subnews2.groupby('Class').describe())
print(' contains :', subnews2.shape)

subnews = news2[news2.Class.str.contains("09employee Injures Hand|29 Employees Burned|3 Employees Killed")]
#print(subnews.groupby('Class').describe())
print(' regex    :', subnews.shape)
```

Result:

```
 ==       : (0, 2)
 contains : (3, 2)
 regex    : (3, 2)
```